# Hiding an image using jquery without also hiding parent DIV background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using Jquery I am targetting an img inside a div to hide when clicked to reveal a video iframe behind it.
This works fine, however, by clicking the div, it also hides the parent div background image.

Please see the working example here by clicking one of the videos on: http://london.illustratedpeople.com/genx.html

It only seems to be a problem in Safari and is working fine in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="profilevideo">
<img src="images/PLAY.png" width="600" height="338" alt="video" class="profile" />
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/78191862?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.profilevideo > img').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
var $img = $(this);
$img.hide();
$img.next().show();
});
```

*Update*
This is a reference to the background change that I am seeing, in order of after click and before click:
[imgur.com/sZ9ps59,wcFVWEj#0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCoHN.png) (1. after click then 2.before)

Thanks in advance, I can't find a way to fix this!

Bradley

Comment: seems fine to me in chrome and safari, they both have the same rendering engine so not sure what the issue is your seeing.

Comment: For me when clicking a video in Safari the background image disappears to black and in Chrome it stays.. This is very odd then?

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard Chrome 28+ is using the [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28layout_engine%29) layout engine now. It's a fork of WebKit, but there are already subtle differences, and they will only increase in number as development continues on the two layout engines.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I could imagine (because I can't really tell from your link) is that when you hide the image, its css `display` property is set to none; because of that, the containing div will will shrink, as there is nothing to force it to its current size anymore.

Try setting the `width` and `height` of the container by hand and see if it still happens.

Comment: Unfortunately If I set the .profilevideo height and width it doesn't seem to make a difference.. And the containing div is already set to width:100%, height 100%... Any more ideas?!

Comment: I'm just downloaded safari. What exactly is the "background image"? What I see is this (before and after click): http://imgur.com/QOdVibL,upuVsCU
It looks like this with Safari, Chrome and Opera 12.16.

Comment: thats bizarre.. the background image is the image behind the white container... for me, this happens http://imgur.com/sZ9ps59,wcFVWEj#0 (1. after click then 2.before)

Comment: Ok something I just noticed: you background image is on a tag called ``<itsnate>``. This doesn't conform to any html standard. Maybe that could be it? Try a ``div`` I guess?

Comment: nope, no difference. If I take away '$img.next().show();' from the jquery, the background doesn't change but the video doesn't show up. Is there any alternative for this line?

Comment: Uh, maybe try ``$img.next('img').show()``.. because of empty text nodes? Other than that it's hard to tell without being able to reproduce or look at it, sorry.

Comment: unfortunately still no joy. I've run out of ideas!